# TypeError: 'float' object not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, floating-point, typeerror

I'm using python 3.2.2 on windows 7 and I'm trying to create a program which accepts 7 numbers and then tells the user how many are positive, how many are negative and how many are zero. This is what I have got so far:

```py
count=7
for i in count:
    num = float(input("Type a number, any number:"))
    if num == 0:
        zero+=1
    elif num > 0:
        positive+=1
    elif num < 0:
        negative+=1

print (positive)
print (negative)
print (zero)
```

But when I run the code I get

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

If I replace float in line 3 with int I get the same problem except it says that the 'int' object is not iterable. I have also tried changing the value of count from 7 to 7.0. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: `for i in count` is not in the tutorial you've attached.

Comment: Please do `print(...)` rather than `print (...)`. In Python 3 `print` is a function, so treat it just like any other function in how you format it. (PEP 8 would also like you to change `a=b` and `a+=b` to `a = b` and `a += b`.)

Comment: You also need to initialize the three variables that you're trying to print: i.e. put `zero = positive = negative = 0` before the loop.

Comment: @cwallenpoole i might not have phrased my question correctly, i trying to complete question 13 in section 3.3 (page 35 in that pdf) and i thought i had used the correct syntax (which i had learnt from other pages on that pdf) but as Chris Morgan pointed out i was missing the range function

ChrisMorgan i will begin removing spaces immediately, thank you again for your help

ekhumoro thanks ill do that now

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`for i in count:` means `for i in 7:`, which won't work. The bit after the `in` should be of an iterable type, not a number. Try this:

```
for i in range(count):
```

Comment: then we get:
     TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 4):

use

> range(count)

int and float are not iterable

Answer (score -1):

In short, check if you have unexpected/"hidden" NaN values in the data passed to a function that expects an iterable such as string, list etc.

As the other answers pointed out, this error occurs when your code expects an iterable but a float is passed to it. Missing data is often represented as NaN (which is a float), so if pass float or a NaN to a function that expects an iterable, it throws this error. Apart from the explicit loop (`for i in 7.0`) in the OP, many of the built-in functions such as `list()`, `set()`, `tuple()`, `dict()`, `enumerate()`, `all()`, `any()`, `max()`, `min()`, `sum()` etc. expect an iterable, so if you pass a float to them, e.g. `max(float('nan'))` or `list(1.5)`, you'll get the error in the title.

Comment: Why are you adding an answer to a question asked 13 years ago and which already has an accepted answer? I downvoted your answer for general cluelessness about how time works. :-)

Comment: @KurtisRader this answer is not for OP (obviously they had their question answered 13 years ago) but for anyone else who comes upon this Q/A because they got the error in the title (this post is the top search engine result for "TypeError: 'float' object not iterable"). You can still answer Stack Overflow questions even if another answer was accepted long time ago; questions aren't closed after answers like in a discussion forum etc. you know.

Comment: I fail to see why Google surfacing this question as the top answer for "TypeError: 'float' object not iterable" requires a new answer that essentially says the same thing as the original answer. Especially since it is obvious (to anyone not a new Python programmer) what the problem was with the O.P.'s example. Your answer doesn't add any value. Hence my downvote. Rather than updating old, trivial, questions that already have an perfectly fine answer you'll add more value answering questions without an answer; or at least adding good comments to those questions.

Comment: @KurtisRader I didn't say the same thing as the top answer though. _"to anyone not a new Python programmer"_  => the people who are coming to this Q/A are probably very new Python programmers who don't know missing values can cause this error or `list()` requires an iterable etc.

Comment: @KurtisRader "Rather than updating old, trivial, questions that already have an perfectly fine answer you'll add more value answering questions without an answer", on the contrary, I think we should close new questions as duplicates of old questions (because most of them are variations of older questions) as much as possible and clean up the older questions and add better answers to them if existing answers are lacking some points. Useful answers being scattered around multiple posts is not good for searchers imo.

Comment: "I think we should close new questions as duplicates of old questions" I agree. I don't see what that has to do with your pointless addition of an answer to a 13 year old question. Note that there are also many newer variations of this question with equally acceptable answers as surfaced by a google search. I think you are the StackOverflow equivalent of Don Quixote.